# Box plot in r: 3 time points, 2 treatments with 2 factors on the same graph

Tags: r, boxplot

I would like to show a simple box plot of data from 3 time points (0, 7 and 28) against abundance.  I want to split the plots into treatment (i.e. CO2 level/Temperature) which will be nested within.  Essentially I have 2 box plots per time point indicating the 2 different treatments.  I Was going to use an overlay but because I have 2 box plots for each time point I am finding it tricky to work out the correct code.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**Help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. Please also read [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) and update your question accordingly!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172560/grouped-horizontal-boxplot-with-bwplot/20174028#20174028) what you're looking for?